# Why Dephi makes Record as Value Type but Class as Refrence Type?

Tags: class, delphi, record

In C++, struct is a special type of class in that all members are public by default. There are no other difference between struct and class.

However, in Delphi, though we can also define functions and procedures in record, just like in class, but record assignment are by value, while class assignment are by reference. Why Delphi will make such an inconsistent design. I cannot understand.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Your words just let me recall the way an object is allocated. Yes, all objects must be dynamically allocated, that is completely different from C++ object instance. Cannot understand why?

Comment: That is just the way Delphi has always worked, since Delphi 1 when `class` was first introduced to replace the old Turbo Pascal `object` (which is *still* "supported" in modern Delphi versions, but is broken).  All classes derive from `TObject` which requires dynamic allocation. And records have always been value types. If you want to know WHY, you would have to ask the original Borland engineers who first designed Delphi. However, records did not always support procedures/functions, that feature was added a decade after Delphi 1, in Delphi 2006.

Comment: Enhanced records with methods is a "new" feature as Remy says. Historically, the old record type is very similar to the c struct type and served the same purpose.

Comment: @RemyLebeau OP would have to ask the developpers of Turbo Pascal as to why records are value types as TP already supported records.

Comment: As for records in modern Delphi vesrions which support adding methods and properties. These are called Advanced Records and have been added in Delphi 2007

Comment: Now which one should you use? That laregly depends on what you need as each of them have some advantages and some dissadvatages.

Comment: Only the designers know for sure, and perhaps with a web search you might find them saying so. The most obvious reason to prefer dynamic allocation is that it enables polymorphism without the issues of object slicing. My expectation is that would have been the biggest single factor. I know that Marco has been talking about exploring automatically allocated objects for performance reasons. Nothig has come of that yet.

Answer (score 1):

Only the Delphi developers can really answer this, but here are my thoughts on the matter:

In order to support inheritance & polymorphism, you need objects to be dynamically allocated, as the compiler can't know ahead of time how much space to allocate to a class instance.

Take, f.ex. this example:

```
TYPE
  TPerson = CLASS
              Name : STRING;
            END;
  TChild  = CLASS(TPerson)
              School : STRING;
            END;
  TAdult  = CLASS(TPerson)
              Company : STRING;
              PhoneNo : STRING;
            END;
  .
  .
  .
  VAR Person : TPerson;
  .
  CASE PersonType OF
    ptChild : Person:=TChild.Create;
    ptAdult : Person:=TAdult.Create;
  END;
```

How much memory should be allocated to "Person" in a program? The compiler can't know. So it doesn't make sense to have class instances be statically allocated memory. Classes need to always be dynamically allocated (to be really useful with inheritance etc.)

In C++ you'd solve this by having Person being a *TPerson, in effect making the Person a reference to the class instance, and not the instance itself, just like in Delphi.

I suspect that the Delphi developers just "saw the light" and decided to go all-in and make classes reference types and not value types.

RECORDs on the other hand, do not support inheritance, so the compiler can always know ahead of time how much memory a record occupies. Also, these come from standard Pascal so in order to be compatible with this, they need to (as in "it's easiest that they") be statically allocated. When Borland Pascal introduced OBJECTs they went down the same path as C++ (and used these for a while in Borland Pascal for Windows, which came before Delphi with VCL) and this created an awful and ugly syntax.

Also, Delphi's CLASS is in some instances more advanced than C++'s (think Virtual Constructors, Class Reference Types etc., which doesn't exist in C++) and I think these features may also have had an influence on deciding to use reference instead of value types.

Comment: "*In order to support inheritance you need objects to be dynamically allocated*" - not true, and C++ does not have that restriction. "*RECORDs on the other hand, do not support inheritance*" - also not true in C++.

Comment: Read on, @RemyLebeau: "(to be really useful with inheritance etc.)". How would you statically allocate "Person" above? There are no RECORDs in C++ - "only" structs. So, RECORDs does _not_ support inheritance.

Comment: What on earth are you talking about when you say that there are no records in C++. They have a different name, but Pascal record and C++ struct are analagous. You are guessing in much of this answer. Perhaps that would be better in comments. Answers should be authoritative.

Comment: I don't agree with you. Actually in C++, one can declare an object of CPerson statically or dynamically. If statically, then the CPerson Person means it just allocate the space of CPerson statically. If dynamically, then CPerson* pPerson means it can allocate spaces dynamically, pPerson =  new CChild means allocate for CChild space, and pPerson = new CAdult means allocate for CAdult space. Thus C++ is much more flexible than Delphi.

Comment: There is a difference between records don't support inheritance, and records can't support inheritance. The former is true, the latter is not, although you appear to infer so.

Comment: I suppose multiple inheritance is another example of why Delphi classes are more advanced than C++ classes

Comment: @alancc: Yes - TPerson Person statically allocates space enough for a TPerson. How do you make a Person reference a TChild? You can't do that with static allocation, only with dynamic one. Thus, in order to support inheritance (with additional fields in the child classes), you *must* allocate the storage using dynamic memory ("new" in C++, .Create in Delphi). If you believe otherwise, please tell me how a statically defined TPerson can point to a TChild or TAdult (decided at runtime).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I don't believe I ever stated that RECORDs *can't* support inheritance - only that they *don't*.

Comment: You did. *"In order to support inheritance you need objects to be dynamically allocated"* Remember that inheritance does not need to encompass polymorphism. Simple inheritance of members is useful enough. Can be done perfectly well with automatic allocation.

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem like you do, since you use a statement by me about OBJECTs to relate to a question about RECORDs. They are two different things, in case you don't know... One supports inheritance, the other doesn't...

Comment: Yes, and you used it to defend your claim that I said that RECORDs *can't* support inheritance. I Have never uttered anything of the sort...

Comment: Of course it is. The likelihood of this, however, is a matter open for interpretation. Please let me know where I have said that RECORDs *can't* support inheritance or retract your statement...

Comment: You said that in order for objects to support inheritance then they must be dynamically allocated. Let us suppose that this claim was true (it isn't). Since records can be allocated automatically it would follow therefore that such records could not support inheritance.

Comment: So, "A stone can't fly, Momma can't fly, ergo Momma is a stone"? Your logic is based on a fallacy...

Comment: I guess you now accept that it is possible to implement inheritance for structured types that are not dynamically allocated. You appear to understand that this happens for C++ structured types, and TP object. Perhaps you can correct that erroneous claim in the sentence that I quoted.

Comment: Nope. It was your attempt to apply an incorrect conclusion based on two statements that has no relation to each other.

Comment: So you do accept that it is possible to implement inheritance for structured types that are not dynamically allocated?

Comment: It depends - do you retract your statement that I have claimed that RECORDs *can't* support inheritance?

Comment: Depends on what exactly? Surely the example of C++ struct and class means that you have to accept this?

Comment: **Moderator Note**: Please be kind and charitable to others. I’m locking this to give everyone a chance to cool down before typing their next sentence.

Comment: @HeartWare `TChild child; TPerson *person = &child;` No dynamic allocation needed. Structs can derive from other structs OR classes, classes can derive from other classes OR structs. Classes/structs in C++ fully support multiple inheritance, classes in Delphi only support multiple inheritance of interfaces, records don't support inheritance at all. So saying that Delphi classes are more advanced than C++ classes is wrong.

Comment: The way I understood it, it's more like "wings are required in order to fly. Birds have wings and stones don't".

Comment: @RemyLebeau: The question was: "please tell me how a statically defined TPerson can point to a TChild _or_ TAdult (decided at _runtime_)". Your reply does not answer this question...

Comment: @RemyLebeau: So, C++ classes have virtual constructors and class reference types? I wasn't aware of this... Thank you for enlightening me...